# C# RSA Encrypting losing bytes

Tags: c#, byte, rsa

I'm working with RSA to message some data between client and  server.

In my client the click button event goes like this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text + "$");
    byte[] outStreamcrypt = cspserver.Encrypt(outStream, false);
    int x = outStreamcrypt.Length;

    byte[] sizes = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);

    serverStream.Write(sizes, 0, sizes.Length);
    serverStream.Write(outStreamcrypt, 0, outStreamcrypt.Length)

    serverStream.Flush();
}
```

Being csp the public key of the server(yes,the server) and serverStream is a NetworkStream.

The problem comes in the server trying to recieve the data and decrypt with his public key:

```
function foo() {
    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    byte[] bytesSize = new byte[4];
    networkStream.Read(bytesSize, 0,4);
    int sizealeer= BitConverter.ToInt32(bytesSize, 0);
    byte[] bytescortos = new byte[sizealeer];
    networkStream.Read(bytescortos, 0, bytescortos.Length);

    var bytesPlainTextData = Program.csp.Decrypt(bytescortos, false);

    string plainTextData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytesPlainTextData);
    Console.WriteLine("Desencriptado - " + clNo + " : " + plainTextData);
}
```

Program.csp is the server key (the same i use to encrypt in the client) ,the problem comes when I try to decrypt, it just gives me 10 bytes as the result of the decryption, and they should be way more.

I create my server key at the very beginning of the server code like this :

```
public static RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
```

Comment: In the encrypt code you are using `Encoding.ASCII` while in the decrypt you use `Encoding.Unicode`

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than badly-formatted pseudo-code.

Comment: Encryption is done with the public key and decryption is done with the private key. Are you sure you got that right?

Comment: (But calling `Stream.Read` and ignoring the return value is never a good idea either...)

Comment: Thank you,  you're all completely correct, i'll take note of this.